# How to create an arrow from one circle to another with KineticJS?

Tags: kineticjs

How to create an arrow from one circle to another with KinectJS?

I have 2 circles with radius=r and stroke=1. How do I do a smooth rounding arrow, or just path from one to another?

thanks

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: well, I don't use the KinectJS, I've made my own~framework.. thanks for interest anyway (;

Comment: It's more object oriented and it's based on Qooxdoo OOP, take a look here if you want. It's not updated, but I can make a push tonight. https://github.com/totty90/TottysTools/tree/master/trunk/source/class/tottystools/Tcanvas

Comment: Nice, can I see this anywhere in action? Like with a simple animation or some other example?

Comment: No :( I don't have it online... but I can make an example in github. You made something like this too? :D

Comment: No, but I'm always interested in new frameworks and efficient ones at that.

Comment: My objective was to be Object oriented, contain Groups that works like in Photoshop, and no strange behavior. For example a group or layer in paper.js is not really a something that you can move and move all it's children. Also the scale is broken in paper.js, I fixed it with some custom code, but I didn't like the way it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just a simple line, you could use

```
 Kinetic.Line({
        points: [circle1.getX(), circle1.getY(), circle2.getX(), circle2.getY()],
        stroke: 'red',
        strokeWidth: 15,
        lineCap: 'round',
        lineJoin: 'round'
 });
```

Curved Lines can be created with a Kinetic.Spline()

```
  var spline = new Kinetic.Spline({
    points: [{
      x: circle1.getX(),
      y: circle1.getY()
    }, {
      x: (circle1.getX()+circle2.getX())/2, 
      y: (circle1.getY()+circle2.getX())/2 +50   // modify this 50 to something that makes it round
    }, {
      x: circle2.getX(),
      y: circle2.getY()
    }],
    stroke: 'red',
    strokeWidth: 2,
    lineCap: 'round',
    tension: 1
  });
```